# ER Diagram - How to display relationships between Entities that are a type of another

Tags: class-diagram, entity

I face a problem in understanding how this situation can be traduced to an ER diagram.

So I have an entity, let's call it `car`, and then, there are another entities, that are a **type of car**. For example, `coupe` `sedan` `SUV` `sports`...

Now, I would simply put a column in `car` called type, if it wasn't because they have some differences that need to be saved in the db. For example, you can put a `racer_id` in a sports car, but I won't be saving a `racer` in a normal car. Or for example, maybe I wan't to know the ammount of weight a `truck` can tow.

You see where I am going. At the end `car` is simply a template of the other ones and in this case, it won't exist only by itself.

These entities clearly depend on `car`, and I understand they are `weak entities`. But how do I put this situation in a diagram? If it is  simply a relation, how should I name it? I can't say that a `car` **"creates"** a `coupe`, I don't know what action defines it's relation.

Any help would be very appreciated. Hope I have explained myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're struggling to describe them, then would such labels or annotations even provide any value to your audience?    If not, why not leave them off and focus only on the relevant information instead?  (i.e. entities, attributes, relationships and their cardinality)

Comment: I would like to show them although I think if I could just mention them that would be the best, so they don't occupy much. You think that's alright? Always saw ER Diagrams as less "flexible"

Comment: It rather depends on your audience and what they expect/require.   Who are you creating this diagram for? What information do they need?  Have they set any kind of standard or rules?   Diagrams are communication tools, so decisions of how/what to represent are about the people who will see/use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to express specialization (e.g. relating cars to coupes), you'll need an [extended ERD model](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/dbms/eermodel.htm) with an `IsA` relationship,  or an UML model instead.

If you want to stick to classical ERD,  you may apply some ORM mapping techniques that express a model that can represent the same relationships, but looses the inheritance logic. For example:

- A weak entity with a composite primary key (but a strong entity with a surrogate primary key and foreign key for the car with a cascade delete would do as well) allows to implement a composition relationship ("has-a", "has parts", "composed off"
- Attributes that are specific to some types of car could be optional for the `Car` (principle of the [Single table inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)) (but how to clarify which one is related to which type?)

Comment: I'll take a look and as soon as I am back with my diagram I'll check if this works for me and then give this the accepted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For an Entity Relationship Diagram, inheritance can best be expressed through Supertypes and Subtypes. An example of the notation can be found [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Databases_and_Data_Structures/Book%3A_Relational_Databases_and_Microsoft_Access_%28McFadyen%29/12%3A_Appendix_B_-_Supertypes_and_Subtypes/12.01%3A_Drawing_Supertypes_and_Subtypes_on_the_ERD).

A subtype is a subgrouping of the entities in an entity type that is meaningful to the organization. A supertype is a generic entity type that has a relationship with one or more subtypes. [Documentation](https://zohaibali45.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/4/5/25455993/03_enhanced_e-r_modeling.pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).